# cpu sensor name vague

Tags: 20.04, temperature, amd-ryzen, lm-sensors, psensor

so I have installed `lm-sensor` and ran the `sensor-detect` saying `yes` to everything, and also installed `psensor`, but both of them don't really show me my cpu temperature.

But a couple of things are named :
`Composite, temp1, tctl, tccd1, tccd2`.

No core or cpu are mentioned.

How can I check my cpu temperature?

[image: image of psensor and lm-sensor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tctl`, `Tccd1` and `Tccd2` are CPU temperature sensors.

You can find more details in AMD docs. I would use `Tctl` for generic use.